# Can SimpleXMLElement::children() have multiple prefixes?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

For SimpleXMLElement::children() method, can I include multiple prefixes as parameters.

Consider following xml. Here, the children('air',true) method can get child elements with "air" as prefix. Similarly, with children('universal',true), I can get child elements with "universal" prefix.

```
<universal:AirCreateReservationRsp xmlns:universal="http://www.travelport.com/schema/universal_v42_0" xmlns:common_v42_0="http://www.travelport.com/schema/common_v42_0" xmlns:air="http://www.travelport.com/schema/air_v42_0" TraceId="trace" TransactionId="6A97EC390A07643C43916EB9FA2934A1" ResponseTime="6143">
    <universal:UniversalRecord LocatorCode="FUEV5F" Version="0" Status="Active">
        <common_v42_0:BookingTraveler Key="gr8AVWGCR064r57Jt0+8bA==" TravelerType="ADT" DOB="1957-05-12" Gender="M" ElStat="A">
            <common_v42_0:BookingTravelerName Prefix="Herr" First="Frederick" Last="Heinrich"/>
            <common_v42_0:DeliveryInfo>
                <common_v42_0:ShippingAddress Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAfRGAAAAAAA==" ElStat="A">
                    <common_v42_0:AddressName>Residence</common_v42_0:AddressName>
                    <common_v42_0:Street>Rossmarkt 6</common_v42_0:Street>
                    <common_v42_0:City>Frankfurt</common_v42_0:City>
                    <common_v42_0:State>HESSE</common_v42_0:State>
                    <common_v42_0:PostalCode>60311</common_v42_0:PostalCode>
                    <common_v42_0:Country>DE</common_v42_0:Country>
                    <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
                </common_v42_0:ShippingAddress>
            </common_v42_0:DeliveryInfo>
            <common_v42_0:PhoneNumber Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAdRGAAAAAAA==" Type="None" Location="FRA" CountryCode="069" Number="261111111" AreaCode="49" ElStat="A">
                <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
            </common_v42_0:PhoneNumber>
            <common_v42_0:Email Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAeRGAAAAAAA==" Type="Home" EmailID="test@travelport.com" ElStat="A">
                <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
            </common_v42_0:Email>
            <common_v42_0:Address Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAgRGAAAAAAA==" ElStat="A">
                <common_v42_0:AddressName>Residence</common_v42_0:AddressName>
                <common_v42_0:Street>Rossmarkt 6</common_v42_0:Street>
                <common_v42_0:City>Frankfurt</common_v42_0:City>
                <common_v42_0:State>HESSE</common_v42_0:State>
                <common_v42_0:PostalCode>60311</common_v42_0:PostalCode>
                <common_v42_0:Country>DE</common_v42_0:Country>
                <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
            </common_v42_0:Address>
        </common_v42_0:BookingTraveler>
        <common_v42_0:ActionStatus Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAoRGAAAAAAA==" Type="TAW" TicketDate="2019-06-20T16:42:00.000+04:00" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" ProviderCode="1G" ElStat="A"/>
        <universal:ProviderReservationInfo Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" ProviderCode="1G" LocatorCode="GQJ1R4" CreateDate="2019-06-18T12:37:55.676+00:00" ModifiedDate="2019-06-18T12:37:55.676+00:00" HostCreateDate="2019-06-18" OwningPCC="62RD"/>\n
        <air:AirReservation LocatorCode="CAUJ2A" CreateDate="2019-06-18T12:37:55.104+00:00" ModifiedDate="2019-06-18T12:37:55.676+00:00">
            <common_v42_0:SupplierLocator SupplierCode="EY" SupplierLocatorCode="QIEPVA" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" CreateDateTime="2019-06-18T12:37:00.000+00:00"/>
            <common_v42_0:BookingTravelerRef Key="gr8AVWGCR064r57Jt0+8bA=="/>
            <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAb+f9BAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" CabinClass="Economy" FlightNumber="5429" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="XNB" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-20T23:50:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T01:10:00.000+04:00" TravelTime="80" Distance="67" ClassOfService="L" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="BUS" MarriageGroup="1" Status="HK" ChangeOfPlane="false" GuaranteedPaymentCarrier="No" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" TravelOrder="1" ProviderSegmentOrder="1" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" ElStat="A">
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2wokqt8Q2BKALSGAAAAAAA==" Origin="XNB" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-20T23:50:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T01:30:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="80" Equipment="BUS" DestinationTerminal="1" AutomatedCheckin="false" ElStat="C"/>
                <air:Connection Duration="105"/>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>ARRIVES AUH TERMINAL 1</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>*010 9W 6567  AT 9285  AZ 5745  BT 5784  GA 9187  HM 6229  HU 87*</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>* *</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>*010 JU 8116  VA 7101  VN 3217*</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" CabinClass="Economy" FlightNumber="246" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="AUH" Destination="COK" DepartureTime="2019-06-21T02:55:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T08:30:00.000+05:30" TravelTime="245" Distance="1749" ClassOfService="L" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="321" MarriageGroup="1" Status="HK" ChangeOfPlane="false" GuaranteedPaymentCarrier="No" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" TravelOrder="2" ProviderSegmentOrder="2" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" ElStat="A">
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAMSGAAAAAAA==" Origin="AUH" Destination="COK" DepartureTime="2019-06-21T02:55:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T08:30:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="245" TravelTime="245" Equipment="321" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="3" AutomatedCheckin="false" ElStat="C"/>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>DEPARTS AUH TERMINAL 3  - ARRIVES COK TERMINAL 3</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>*010 9W 6616  XY 3246*</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>ADD ADVANCE PASSENGER INFORMATION SSRS DOCA/DOCO/DOCS</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>PERSONAL DATA WHICH IS PROVIDED TO US IN CONNECTION</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>WITH YOUR TRAVEL MAY BE PASSED TO GOVERNMENT AUTHORITIES</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>FOR BORDER CONTROL AND AVIATION SECURITY PURPOSES</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAf+f9BAAAAA==" Group="1" Carrier="EY" CabinClass="Economy" FlightNumber="247" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="COK" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T10:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T12:30:00.000+04:00" TravelTime="240" Distance="1749" ClassOfService="L" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="321" MarriageGroup="2" Status="HK" ChangeOfPlane="false" GuaranteedPaymentCarrier="No" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" TravelOrder="3" ProviderSegmentOrder="3" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" ElStat="A">
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2wokqt8Q2BKANSGAAAAAAA==" Origin="COK" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T10:00:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T12:30:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="240" TravelTime="240" Equipment="321" OriginTerminal="3" DestinationTerminal="1" AutomatedCheckin="false" ElStat="C"/>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>DEPARTS COK TERMINAL 3  - ARRIVES AUH TERMINAL 1</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>*010 9W 6617  XY 3247*</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>ADD ADVANCE PASSENGER INFORMATION SSRS DOCA/DOCO/DOCS</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>PERSONAL DATA WHICH IS PROVIDED TO US IN CONNECTION</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>WITH YOUR TRAVEL MAY BE PASSED TO GOVERNMENT AUTHORITIES</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>FOR BORDER CONTROL AND AVIATION SECURITY PURPOSES</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAh+f9BAAAAA==" Group="2" Carrier="EY" CabinClass="Economy" FlightNumber="5426" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="AUH" Destination="XNB" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T20:30:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T21:50:00.000+04:00" TravelTime="80" Distance="67" ClassOfService="L" ETicketability="Yes" Equipment="BUS" MarriageGroup="2" Status="HK" ChangeOfPlane="false" GuaranteedPaymentCarrier="No" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" TravelOrder="4" ProviderSegmentOrder="4" OptionalServicesIndicator="false" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" ElStat="A">
                <air:FlightDetails Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAOSGAAAAAAA==" Origin="AUH" Destination="XNB" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T20:30:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T22:10:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="80" Equipment="BUS" OriginTerminal="1" AutomatedCheckin="false" ElStat="C"/>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>DEPARTS AUH TERMINAL 1</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
                <common_v42_0:SellMessage>*010 9W 6554  AZ 4158  BT 5749  JU 8114  VA 7154*</common_v42_0:SellMessage>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirPricingInfo Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAk+f9BAAAAA==" TotalPrice="OMR150.800" BasePrice="AED760" ApproximateTotalPrice="OMR150.800" ApproximateBasePrice="OMR80.000" EquivalentBasePrice="OMR80.000" Taxes="OMR70.800" LatestTicketingTime="2019-06-18T23:59:00.000+04:00" TrueLastDateToTicket="2019-06-18T23:59:00.000+04:00" PricingMethod="Guaranteed" Refundable="true" Exchangeable="true" IncludesVAT="false" ETicketability="Yes" PlatingCarrier="EY" ProviderCode="1G" ProviderReservationInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA==" AirPricingInfoGroup="1" PricingType="StoredFare" ElStat="A" FareCalculationInd="G">
                <air:FareInfo Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAHSGAAAAAAA==" FareBasis="LLRM3AE/" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="XNB" Destination="AUH" EffectiveDate="2019-06-18T00:00:00.000+04:00" NotValidBefore="2019-06-20" NotValidAfter="2019-06-20" PseudoCityCode="62RD" ElStat="C">
                    <air:FareTicketDesignator Value="YV"/>
                    <common_v42_0:Endorsement Value="NON ENDO/ REF"/>
                    <air:BaggageAllowance>
                        <air:MaxWeight Value="30" Unit="Kilograms"/>
                    </air:BaggageAllowance>
                </air:FareInfo>
                <air:FareInfo Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAISGAAAAAAA==" FareBasis="LLRM3AE/" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="AUH" Destination="COK" EffectiveDate="2019-06-18T00:00:00.000+04:00" Amount="NUC148.65" NotValidBefore="2019-06-21" NotValidAfter="2019-06-21" PseudoCityCode="62RD" ElStat="C">
                    <air:FareTicketDesignator Value="YV"/>
                    <air:FareSurcharge Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAWSGAAAAAAA==" Type="Other" Amount="NUC3.00" ElStat="A" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                    <air:FareSurcharge Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAXSGAAAAAAA==" Type="Weekend Surcharge" Amount="NUC13.61" ElStat="A" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                    <air:FareSurcharge Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAYSGAAAAAAA==" Type="Other" Amount="NUC6.80" ElStat="A" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                    <common_v42_0:Endorsement Value="NON ENDO/ REF"/>
                    <air:BaggageAllowance>
                        <air:MaxWeight Value="30" Unit="Kilograms"/>
                    </air:BaggageAllowance>
                </air:FareInfo>
                <air:FareInfo Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAJSGAAAAAAA==" FareBasis="LLRM1AE/" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="COK" Destination="AUH" EffectiveDate="2019-06-18T00:00:00.000+04:00" NotValidBefore="2019-06-23" NotValidAfter="2019-06-23" PseudoCityCode="62RD" ElStat="C">
                    <air:FareTicketDesignator Value="YV"/>
                    <common_v42_0:Endorsement Value="NON ENDO/ REF"/>
                    <air:BaggageAllowance>
                        <air:MaxWeight Value="30" Unit="Kilograms"/>
                    </air:BaggageAllowance>
                </air:FareInfo>
                <air:FareInfo Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAKSGAAAAAAA==" FareBasis="LLRM1AE/" PassengerTypeCode="ADT" Origin="AUH" Destination="XNB" EffectiveDate="2019-06-18T00:00:00.000+04:00" Amount="NUC56.08" NotValidBefore="2019-06-23" NotValidAfter="2019-06-23" PseudoCityCode="62RD" ElStat="C">
                    <air:FareTicketDesignator Value="YV"/>
                    <air:FareSurcharge Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAdSGAAAAAAA==" Type="Other" Amount="NUC3.00" ElStat="A" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAh+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                    <air:FareSurcharge Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAeSGAAAAAAA==" Type="Other" Amount="NUC6.80" ElStat="A" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAh+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                    <common_v42_0:Endorsement Value="NON ENDO/ REF"/>
                    <air:BaggageAllowance>
                        <air:MaxWeight Value="30" Unit="Kilograms"/>
                    </air:BaggageAllowance>
                </air:FareInfo>
                <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="L" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKAHSGAAAAAAA==" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAb+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="L" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKAISGAAAAAAA==" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="L" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKAJSGAAAAAAA==" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAf+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:BookingInfo BookingCode="L" CabinClass="Economy" FareInfoRef="2wokqt8Q2BKAKSGAAAAAAA==" SegmentRef="RzO2Zt3R2BKAh+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="AE" Amount="OMR7.900" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAl+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="F6" Amount="OMR3.700" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAm+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="TP" Amount="OMR0.600" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAn+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="ZR" Amount="OMR1.200" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAo+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="WO" Amount="OMR2.300" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAp+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="YQ" Amount="OMR54.600" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAq+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:TaxInfo Category="YR" Amount="OMR0.500" Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAr+f9BAAAAA=="/>
                <air:FareCalc>DXB EY X/AUH EY COK Q DXBCOK3.00Q DXBCOK13.61Q DXBCOK6.80 125.24LLRM3AE/YV EY X/AUH EY DXB Q COKDXB3.00Q COKDXB6.80 46.29LLRM1AE/YV NUC204.74END ROE3.67275</air:FareCalc>
                <air:PassengerType Code="ADT" BookingTravelerRef="gr8AVWGCR064r57Jt0+8bA==">
                    <air:FareGuaranteeInfo GuaranteeDate="2019-06-18" GuaranteeType="Guaranteed"/>
                </air:PassengerType>
                <common_v42_0:BookingTravelerRef Key="gr8AVWGCR064r57Jt0+8bA=="/>
                <air:ChangePenalty>
                    <air:Amount>OMR10.00</air:Amount>
                </air:ChangePenalty>
                <air:CancelPenalty>
                    <air:Amount>OMR21.00</air:Amount>
                </air:CancelPenalty>
                <air:TicketingModifiersRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAhSGAAAAAAA=="/>
            </air:AirPricingInfo>
            <air:TicketingModifiers PlatingCarrier="EY" Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAhSGAAAAAAA==" ElStat="A">
                <air:DocumentSelect IssueElectronicTicket="true"/>
            </air:TicketingModifiers>
        </air:AirReservation>
        <common_v42_0:AgencyInfo>
            <common_v42_0:AgentAction ActionType="Created" AgentCode="uAPI4777060768-7d89df01" BranchCode="P7099377" AgencyCode="S7099370" EventTime="2019-06-18T12:37:50.178+00:00"/>
        </common_v42_0:AgencyInfo>
        <common_v42_0:FormOfPayment Key="jwt2mcK1Qp27I2xfpcCtAw==" Type="Cash" Reusable="false" ProfileKey="+gr4dnY9RJG00MovXy6nJg==" ElStat="A">
            <common_v42_0:ProviderReservationInfoRef Key="2wokqt8Q2BKARSGAAAAAAA=="/>
        </common_v42_0:FormOfPayment>
    </universal:UniversalRecord>
    <air:AirSolutionChangedInfo ReasonCode="Schedule">
        <air:AirPricingSolution Key="2wokqt8Q2BKAXRGAAAAAAA==">
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAb+f9BAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="5429" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="XNB" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-20T23:40:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T01:20:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="100" Distance="67" ClassOfService="L" Equipment="BUS" Status="NN" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="O and D cache or polled status used with different local status" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="Fare Specific Fare Quote Unbooked" OptionalServicesIndicator="false">
                <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</air:CodeshareInfo>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAc+f9BAAAAA==" Origin="XNB" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-20T23:40:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T01:20:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="100" Distance="67"/>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAd+f9BAAAAA==" Group="0" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="246" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="AUH" Destination="COK" DepartureTime="2019-06-21T02:55:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T08:30:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="245" TravelTime="245" Distance="1749" ClassOfService="L" Equipment="321" Status="NN" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="O and D cache or polled status used with different local status" TravelOrder="1" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="Fare Specific Fare Quote Unbooked" OptionalServicesIndicator="false">
                <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</air:CodeshareInfo>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAe+f9BAAAAA==" Origin="AUH" Destination="COK" DepartureTime="2019-06-21T02:55:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-21T08:30:00.000+05:30" FlightTime="245" TravelTime="245" Distance="1749"/>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAf+f9BAAAAA==" Group="1" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="247" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="COK" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T09:35:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T12:05:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="240" TravelTime="240" Distance="1749" ClassOfService="L" Equipment="321" Status="NN" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="O and D cache or polled status used with different local status" TravelOrder="2" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="Fare Specific Fare Quote Unbooked" OptionalServicesIndicator="false">
                <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</air:CodeshareInfo>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAg+f9BAAAAA==" Origin="COK" Destination="AUH" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T09:35:00.000+05:30" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T12:05:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="240" TravelTime="240" Distance="1749"/>
            </air:AirSegment>
            <air:AirSegment Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAh+f9BAAAAA==" Group="1" Carrier="EY" FlightNumber="5426" ProviderCode="1G" Origin="AUH" Destination="XNB" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T20:00:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T21:40:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="100" Distance="67" ClassOfService="L" Equipment="BUS" Status="NN" ParticipantLevel="Secure Sell" LinkAvailability="true" PolledAvailabilityOption="O and D cache or polled status used with different local status" TravelOrder="3" AvailabilitySource="S" AvailabilityDisplayType="Fare Specific Fare Quote Unbooked" OptionalServicesIndicator="false">
                <air:CodeshareInfo OperatingCarrier="EY">ETIHAD AIRWAYS</air:CodeshareInfo>
                <air:FlightDetails Key="RzO2Zt3R2BKAi+f9BAAAAA==" Origin="AUH" Destination="XNB" DepartureTime="2019-06-23T20:00:00.000+04:00" ArrivalTime="2019-06-23T21:40:00.000+04:00" FlightTime="100" TravelTime="100" Distance="67"/>
            </air:AirSegment>
        </air:AirPricingSolution>
    </air:AirSolutionChangedInfo>
</universal:AirCreateReservationRsp>
```

What I actually need is a way to use single children() method with "air" and "universal" prefix. Is something like children('air,universal',true) possible?

Comment: Take a look at SimpleXMLElement::xpath().

Comment: You can only get the children of 1 prefix at a time.